# Seven Sons equals Gan Eden?

Tags: sources-mekorot, women, men-male, gan-eden, children

Is there a source for the idea that a woman who has seven boys in row gets automatic entrance to Gan Eden?

Comment: A quick look produced this similar query (with no answers) http://www.ottmall.com/mj_ht_arch/v28/mj_v28i26.html#CHS

Comment: in general, the truth contained in claims that something gets you automatic entrance to Gan Eden is negligible.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge there is no source for this. I have searched in Hebrew for this idea and have found no source for this either.

Comment: Where did you first hear this idea? Perhaps someone told you this in relation to the story of Chana and her seven sons? For if so, Chana did not enter Gan Eden because she had seven sons per se, but because all of them died al kiddush Hashem. Also, welcome to Mi Yodeya, Mina.

Comment: IIRC this is listed in a work collecting all the aphorisms popularly (mis)attributed to Hazal.

Comment: @ezra Woops, sorry bout that. Didn't notice the comment. I'll delete mine.

Answer (score 5):

Rav Ahron Leib Shteiman in Sifsei Aiyel pg.63 was once asked this question and he laughed and said there is no such thing and there is no source. He added in a joking fashion "go ask the minister of Gan Eden".

[image]

Comment: Edit: He didn't LAUGH, he smiled! :-)